# Safari and other programs using too much RAM with barely any tabs open. Happens daily since Yosemite

Tags: safari, macbook-pro, macos, memory, preview

I've noticed a drop battery life as well as performance from my macbook since the new Yosemite update a week ago.
The performance slows down greatly, even with my 8gb of ram. Animations are very choppy and the entire system just slows down.

This Safari issue as well as Preview happens daily for school. Any ideas?

[image: My activity monitor, memory tab]

Comment: What is the model/year of your macbook? PS Clean Install might solve this issue.

Comment: Summer 2013. Clean install of Yosemite or safari?

Comment: I would do clean install of OSX.

Comment: Any reason why? Or just a common problem?

Comment: How many Safari tabs do you have open? Also, try setting Activity Monitor's View to 'All processes, Hierarchically' then find Safari again & see how many child processes it's running & what they are consuming.